# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPhone but not on Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I get this exc_bad_access when I run the application on device ( iPhone 4 ). I tried enabling zombies by setting NSZombieEnabled to YES. Application crashes with exc_bad_access but doesn't give me the reason for crash.

I fixed all errors that Build and Analyze , scan-build using clang analyzer flagged. Works perfectly fine on simulator. App parsers xml using libxml2 and displays content on UITableView. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: added (gdb) info threads response. Is there any other way to debug the EXC_BAD_ACCESS that I missed ?

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x33a0daba in CALayerStateRelease ()
#1  0x339f3d9e in CALayerFreeTransaction ()
#2  0x339f3330 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#3  0x33a179bc in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#4  0x3082823c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#5  0x308280b0 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#6  0x3081f28c in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#7  0x3081f17e in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#8  0x31e445f2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#9  0x31e4469e in GSEventRun ()
#10 0x31e51122 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#11 0x31e4f12e in UIApplicationMain ()
#12 0x0000285e in main (argc=1, argv=0x2ffff53c) at /Users/Home/Desktop/ProductNavigation_libxml2_regular/main.m:14
(gdb) info threads
  6  (Thread 0x770b: user=0.000000 system=0.000000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x3027a19c in __workq_kernreturn ()
  5  (Thread 0x6e07: user=0.010000 system=0.010000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x30224060 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
  4  (Thread 0x6103: user=0.030000 system=0.030000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x301ffc98 in mach_msg_trap ()
  3  (Thread 0x2003: user=0.000000 system=0.000000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x301ffc98 in mach_msg_trap ()
  2  (Thread 0x1703: user=0.000000 system=0.000000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x3022c330 in kevent ()
* 1  (Thread 0x0307: user=1.160000 system=1.160000 cpu=0 sleep_time=0) 0x33a0daba in CALayerStateRelease ()
(gdb)
```

**Update#2:** Another Stack Trace that points to UITableView

```
#0  0x3002d844 in objc_msgSend_stret ()
#1  0x31ed5b8e in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager(UITableViewCellLayoutManagerStatic) _editingAccessoryRectForCell:offscreen:] ()
#2  0x31ed5374 in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager(UITableViewCellLayoutManagerStatic) _reorderSeparatorRectForCell:offscreen:] ()
#3  0x31ed5266 in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager reorderSeparatorEndingRectForCell:forNewEditingState:] ()
#4  0x31ed48ae in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager layoutSubviewsOfCell:] ()
#5  0x3206ae24 in -[UITableViewCellLayoutManagerSubtitle layoutSubviewsOfCell:] ()
#6  0x31ed37c0 in -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] ()
#7  0x31e5cbc6 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#8  0x308362ea in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] ()
#9  0x339f9948 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#10 0x339f9700 in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded ()
#11 0x339f34ca in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#12 0x339f32e0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#13 0x33a179bc in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
#14 0x3082823c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#15 0x308280b0 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#16 0x3081f6ba in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#17 0x3081f276 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#18 0x3081f17e in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#19 0x31e445f2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#20 0x31e4469e in GSEventRun ()
#21 0x31e51122 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#22 0x31e4f12e in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: may be you can provide some code to show what you're doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with XML Parser,freeing the parser context after parsing is complete used to crash. Moved that to dealloc method fixed issue. Thanks everyone for looking into my post and spending some time on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Let it run with NSZombies enabled, and then check what gets released while it should be deallocated (this really sounds like a memory issue, especially because of the stack trace).

When you found the source, fix it and be happy :)

Comment: Thats the first thing I did. Project -> Active Executable -> Arguements NSZombieEnabled to YES. Nothing on the debugger console upon EXC_BAD_ACCESS. :(

Comment: @MacDev wow, thats strange. I'd bet that there is a bad memory access somewhere, because thats always the reason when I get those crashes in one of Apples frameworks.

Comment: These debugging tools are comically bad, but at least NSZombie tells you which object something was called on. I mean "__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__" - how obscure can it get? In my case I don't think it was any kind of observer...

Comment: @n13 Run it in Instruments with the Zombies tool and watch the complete lifecycle of your object. The debugging tools are exceptionally good, if you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

From the point in your code where you commented the print statement follow the program flow and verify if your objects are properly instantiated and are also properly released.

It appears to me that the program crashes when it is releasing something that is not there (anymore or not yet). One of the last message is `UITableViewCellLayout`, that is called from somewhere where the table cells are setup (cellForRowAtIndexPath and so on).

Answer (score 0):

From the limited info there, it looks like it could be a print problem. Are you logging to a file? The directory you are logging to (i.e. where you're allowed to write files to from your app) could be different on the device and simulator. I've had similar problems in the past when I was logging some debug info.

Comment: I am not logging to a file. I was printing some tempString to console for debugging. I commented it out which has no effect whatsoever.